# How to implement OpenSAML library in a Web Application using servlets for SSO

Tags: servlets, web-applications, saml, opensaml

I have a Web Application built with Servlet , I don't know how to implement SAML for Web SSO and there is no perfect guideline to use it in servlets. Where to initiate or initialize the openSAML and how to redirect to IDP from login page and where to consume the responses ,. 
I have seen a couple of samples like [spring-security-saml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml) but they none of the examples are servlet based.
If I get a suitable example which uses servlet it would be a great help .

Answer (score 1):

Check OpenSAML examples by Stefan Rasmusson. 
https://github.com/rasmusson/webprofile-ref-project?files=1

Comment: Thanks for the reply , still its complex to understand , It would be cool with sample from login to logout with application.

Comment: Why do you bother to implement a standards compliant SAMLv2 SP yourself? SAMLv2 is more than consuming a SAML assertion. Of course you can integrate Spring SAML security extention with your app as it's very likely that your 'servlets' are packaged in a JEE WebApp.

Comment: My book, A Guide to OpenSAML https://gumroad.com/l/a-guide-to-opensaml-v3, is built upon those code samples and explain how they work in detail.